# Directory Name + File Name to Text File

Tags: python, file, directory, text-files

I have many directories with files in them.  I want to create a comma delimited txt file showing directory name, and the files that are within that particular directory, see example below:

**What I'm looking for:**

```
DirName,Filename 
999,123.tif 
999,1234.tif 
999,abc.tif 
900,1236.tif 
900,xyz.tif 
...etc
```

The python code below pushes a list of those file paths into a text file, however I'm unsure of how to format the list as described above.

**My current code looks like:**

**Update**

I've been able to format the text file now, however I'm noticing all the directory   names/filenames are not being written to the text file.  It is only writing ~4000 of the ~8000 dir/files.  Is there some sort limit that I'm reaching with the text file number of rows, the list (mylist) size, or some bad file dir/file character that is stopping it (see updated code below)?

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
root = r'C:\temp'
mylist = ['2']
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
     for name in files:
          mylist.append(os.path.join(path, name))

txt = open(r'C:\temp\output.txt', 'w')
txt.write('dir' + ',' + 'file' + '\n')
for item in mylist:
     list = mylist.pop(0)
     dir, filename = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(list)), os.path.basename(list)
     txt.write(dir + ',' + filename + '\n')

with open(r'C:\temp\output.txt', 'r') as f:
     read_data = f.read()
```

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

You could get the absolute file paths and then do the following

```
import os.path
p = "/tmp/999/123.tif"
dir, filename = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(p)), os.path.basename(p)
```

Result:

```
In [21]: dir
Out[21]: '999'

In [22]: filename
Out[22]: '123.tif'
```

Also consider using [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module to write this kind of files.

```
import csv
import os.path

# You already have a list of absolute paths
files = ["/tmp/999/123.tif"]

# csv writer
with open('/tmp/out.csv', 'wb') as out_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',')
    csv_writer.writerow(('DirName','Filename'))
    for f in files:
        csv_writer.writerow((os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(f)), 
                             os.path.basename(f)))
```

Comment: under your csv snippet, should p be files?  If so, I'm getting an error that says can not concatenate 'str' and 'list'.

Comment: Sorry @artwork21, it's fixed now, `p` was really `f` (the current path of the file)